# Chaining REST calls in a pipeline while managing errors

Tags: error-handling, f#, method-chaining, function-composition

Coming from nodejs where I could chain asynchronous events using [Promises and then operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) I'm trying to explore how things are done in idiomatic F#.

The calls I'm trying to chain are HTTP rest calls on some entity from creation to update to uploading images to publishing.

Function composition says the output of one function should match the input of the second one to be composed and that common input and output in my case will be `string`, i.e. JSON serialized string as input and output of all of these functions.

I've learned that you can compose functions using `>>` operator. Ideally functions should not throw errors but things happen with IO, for instance in this case what if the id of the entity I'm trying to create exists etc.

The unknown and the question is what happens if an error occurs during the chained sequence, how the caller will know what went wrong along with description message? The operation could fail in the middle or towards the end or right in the beginning of the chain sequence.

What I'm expecting from these functions upon error to stop executing the chain and return the error message to the caller. Error message is also a JSON `string` so there's no incompatibility between inputs and outputs of a function so you know.

I looked at [Choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.choice%5B't1%2C't2%5D-union-%5Bfsharp%5D) too but not sure if that's the direction I should be going for.

The code is not necessarily complete and all I'm looking for a is a direction to research further to get answers and possibly improve this question. Here's some code to start with.

```
let create schema =
    // POST request
    """{"id": 1, "title": "title 1"}""" // result output

let update schema =
    // PUT request, update title
    """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2"}""" // output

let upload schema = 
    // PUT request, upload image and add thumbnail to json
    """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg"}""" 

let publish schema =
    // PUT request, publish the entity, add url for the entity
    if response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK then
        """{"code": "100", "message": "file size above limit"}"""
    else
        """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg", "url": "http://example.com/1"}"""

let chain = create >> update >> upload >> publish
```

---

**Edit - Attempt**

Trying to parameterize the image thumbnail in the upload part

```
let create (schema: string) : Result<string,string> =
    Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 1"}""" // result output

let update (schema: string) : Result<string,string>  =
    Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2"}""" // output

let upload2 (img: string) (schema: string) : Result<string,string> =
    printf "upload image %s\n" img
    let statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    match statusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.OK -> Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg"}"""
    | x -> Error (sprintf "%A happened" x)

let publish (schema: string) =
    let statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
    match statusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.OK -> Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg", "url": "http://example.com/1"}"""
    | _ -> Error """{"code": "100", "message": "couldn't publish, file size above limit"}"""

let chain = create >> Result.bind update >> Result.bind (upload2 "image.jpg") >> Result.bind publish
```

Comment: "Promises and then operator" are actually a poor man's implementation of monadic computation (but for one specific scenario) in JavaScript. Guess where that idea came from in the first place? :-)

Comment: :) yes it has it's shortfalls, by the way is this what a monad is based on the given answer? I read but still trying to comprehend

Comment: Yes, this is what a monad is, more or less.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, so in other words monad is a pipeline of functions accepting single input and returning single output, and because of an error at any stage, the control returns to the caller with the error or result upon success?

Comment: No. What you described is only a special case of monad. The concept is more abstract than that, which makes it able to express more ways to structure computation that just "early return on error", but also makes it harder to explain in simple terms.

Comment: interesting... it occurs to me like a very magical mystical concept, almost like a cult :-) from those haskell guys. I want to go deep dive in monads using F#, any references please

Comment: Start with simpler things. Railway-oriented programming is a good place to start. Once you get a few functional concepts in your active memory, you'll be able to make new connections.

Comment: I've added some example code in an addendum, please comment about it too.

Comment: Please do not turn your question into a discussion board. This is not StackOverflow's format. If you have more questions, feel free to post them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good general approach to this problem is wrapping your functions' return values in a Choice/Either-like type and using a higher-order function to *bind* them together such that a *failure* propagates/short-circuits with some meaningful data. F# has a `Result` type with a `bind` function that can be used like this:

```
type MyResult = Result<string,string>
let f1 x : MyResult = printfn "%s" x; Ok "yep"
let f2 x : MyResult = printfn "%s" x; Ok "yep!"
let f3 x : MyResult = printfn "%s" x; Error "nope :("
let fAll = f1 >> Result.bind f2 >> Result.bind f3

> fAll "howdy";;
howdy
yep
yep!
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,string> = Error "nope :("
```

The first two functions succeed, but the third fails and so you get an `Error` value back.

Also check out this article on [Railway-oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/).

**Update** to be more specific to your example:

```
let create (schema: string) : Result<string,string> =
    Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 1"}""" // result output
let update (schema: string) : Result<string,string>  =
    Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2"}""" // output
let upload (schema: string) = 
    let statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    match statusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.OK -> Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg"}"""
    | x -> Error (sprintf "%A happened" x)
let publish (schema: string) =
    let statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
    match statusCode with
    | HttpStatusCode.OK -> Ok """{"id": 1, "title": "title 2", "thumbnail": "image.jpg", "url": "http://example.com/1"}"""
    | _ -> Error """{"code": "100", "message": "file size above limit"}"""
let chain =
  create >> Result.bind update >> Result.bind upload >> Result.bind publish
```

Comment: thanks for the direction, can you please append the answer with a solution using my function calls, I'll understand more. Just you know I added an error condition in my publish function.

Comment: awesome, thank you, I appreciate a lot. Reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results also made more sense. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: I've been researching and looking at this `create >> Result.bind update`, any explanation in simple english on what `Result.bind update` does? Please.

Comment: @Developer11 `Result.bind` takes 1) a function that returns a `Result<>` and 2) a `Result<>`. If the `Result` is an `Error`, it simply returns it; if it's an `Ok` then it executes the given function and returns its `Result`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it starts to reveal the real picture, last I forgot  that upload function needs another argument to be passed, i.e. image thumbnail file path to be uploaded, `let upload (schema: string, image: string)` how custom parameterization can work in chaining procedures like these?

Comment: Taylor, I've attempted based on your solution, please see my edit. function `upload2` and `chain` expression is different, I'm attempting while currying `upload2` while passing thumbnail image. Please review, I'm not sure if this can be achieved in F#?

Comment: in javascript I used to achieve it via closures or binding a function with image argument and then piping into the chain, any ideas?

Comment: I fixed something with parameters, can you please review the attempt again. Need your blessings.

Comment: @Developer11 your updates look like they'd work, of course there's only one way to find out :)

Comment: yes it's working :) It's just that I'm asking for your blessing if this is how it's supposed to be when it comes to idiomatic F#. It's just I'm used to do things differently in javascript where same effect is achieved via `bind` and `apply` and these keywords are in F# too, just wondering if there was a better idiomatic way that I missed, I'm not just into getting things done but getting done in the right way.

Comment: Hi Taylor, mind looking at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370853/chaining-async-rest-calls-in-a-pipeline-while-managing-errors

Comment: Taylor, are you there, need your help, the question is still unresolved and i'm able to articulate, please point me in the direction of applying railway oriented programming with async functions. you can post an answer to the linked question

Comment: re-attempting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370853/chaining-async-rest-calls-in-a-pipeline-while-managing-errors