# chaining async rest calls in a pipeline while managing errors

Tags: asynchronous, f#, function-composition

Building on previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226552/chaining-rest-calls-in-a-pipeline-while-managing-errors) based on synchronous calls, how do we approach asynchronous methodology in the following scenario.

```
let fetch1 (result: string) : Result<string, string> =
    try
        use request = WebRequest.Create("http://bing.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
        use response = request.GetResponse()
        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Ok "success"
    with
        | :? WebException as e ->
        Error "error with the url"

let fetch2 (result: string) : Result<string, string> =
    try
        use request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
        use response = request.GetResponse()
        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Ok "success"
    with
        | :? WebException as e ->
        Error "error with the url"

let fetch3 (result: string) : Result<string, string> =
     try
         use request = WebRequest.Create("http://invalid.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
         use response = request.GetResponse()
         use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
         let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
         Ok "success"
     with
         | :? WebException as e ->
         Error "error with the url"
```

**Test**

```
let chain = fetch1 >> Result.bind fetch2 >> Result.bind fetch3

match chain("") with 
| Ok message -> Debug.WriteLine(message)
| Error error -> Debug.WriteLine(error)
```

**Attempt**

```
let fetch1 (result: string) :Result<string, string> = async {
    try
        use! request = WebRequest.Create("http://bing.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
        use response = request.GetResponse()
        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Ok "success"
    with
        | :? WebException as e ->
        Error "error with the url"
 }
```

**Error**

> > This expression was epxected to have type 'Result' but here has type 'Async<'a>'

Comment: Well, you changed your expression to an `async`, but you still insist that its type should be `Result<string, string>`. No wonder the compiler is baffled. What's not clear to you?

Comment: what should be the return type, and any fixes within the code, I believe something like `use! request`, appreciate help with the code in the answer. thanks

Comment: `async` computations are of type `Async<_>`, as the compiler is helpfully telling you. You need to decide what type should be wrapped in `Async<_>` - i.e. what type should your async computation produce.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not as fluent as you, i'm a beginner level, I can understand well with a complete code picture.

Comment: you mean like this `Async<Result<Article, Error>>`? I'm getting other errors in the body now, that's why I suggested a complete code example please

Comment: I think your example is broken - why do all the `fetch` functions take `result` argument that is not used?

Comment: it's a small fictitious example, the real case has arguments and each function has a different behavior, my objective is to see how async functions are chained together

Answer (score 2):

You should explain what exception handling mechanism are you actually trying to implement here. For many things, using just normal F# built-in exceptions will work perfectly fine.

You are using `Result.bind` which is a way to implement an exception handling behaviour where, if any step throws an exception, the overall computation will fail. Is this what you want to achieve? If so, you can just rely on built-in F# async support for exception handling and have `try .. with` in the async computation that calls the two `fetch` functions. A minimal example:

```
let fetch url = async {
  use wc = new WebClient()
  let! res = wc.AsyncDownloadString(System.Uri(url))
  return res }

let fetchAllOrNothing = async {
  try 
    let! goog = fetch "http://www.google.com"
    let! bing = fetch "http://www.bing.com"
    return Some(goog.Length, bing.Length)
  with _ ->
    return None }
```

If you want to call all fetch functions and fail only if all of them fail, then you will need to wrap individual `fetch` functions with exception handlers (as you do) and then pick the first result. Using normal F# option type, this can be done using `Array.tryPick`:

```
let fetch url = async {
  try
    use wc = new WebClient()
    let! res = wc.AsyncDownloadString(System.Uri(url))
    return Some res 
  with _ -> 
    return None }

let fetchFirstOne = async {
  let! all = 
    [ fetch "http://www.google.com"
      fetch "http://www.bing.com" ] |> Async.Parallel
  return Array.tryPick (fun x -> x) all }
```

If you are starting with F#, then it is a lot easier to get started using things like core `async` functions and options - once you are comfortable with those, it makes sense to look at more sophisticated methods.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm getting confused here, fetching url's is an example, my real work has a lot more and different things in each, and has to be different individual functions, can you please use my example with 3 function calls fetch1, fetch2 and fetch3, I can't generalize all in one function call. otherwise I've to change question and get rid of fetching urls and come up with a different example.

Comment: @Developer11 just replace `fetch "oneUrl"` and `fetch "anotherUrl"` in my example with your `work1 ()` and `work2 ()` functions - the rest stays the same.

Comment: what happens to the chain, how the chain will work, shall i get rid of Result.bind from there? I also want to see the signature of chain calls following with match statement . as per my "Test"

Comment: You do not need `Result.bind` - my example is self contained - it shows you two ways of composing `async` computations.

Comment: ok, please show me the compose chain statements, and then I can get back to testing

Comment: @Developer11 The composed functions are `fetchAllOrNothing` and `fetchFirstOne` in my sample. I'm afraid adding more details is beyond what can reasonably be done in a StackOverflow answer - you might find it easier to understand those concepts from one of the F# books (I wrote one, which covers F# asyncs in enough detail: http://manning.com/petricek)

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing out, just I can't wrap my head around it when I don't see the examples as per the question. I'll work on this and test and get back to you on this,

Comment: i'm afraid we are still missing the point here, I don't see function composition in here, no function is piping the result to the other. It has to be chain of async functions piping the results to the other and in case any one of them throws exception, the chain breaks and error is passed to the caller

Comment: @Developer11 There is no operator for function composition needed in this example - in the first case, you just have multiple `let!` bindings and in the second case, you have a list of functions passed to `Async.Parallel`. Both of these are ways of composing functions - and they are simpler ways of doing that than using operators or `bind` functions.

Comment: there's a typo, `DownloadStringAsync`, it's also throwing an error, `This expression was expected to have type Async<a> but here has type unit` for the line `let! res = wc.DownloadStringAsync(System.Uri(url))`

Comment: @Developer11 Add `open System.Net`.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKs3N.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYCEb.png System.Net is open, I think we have to re-attempt this with another question, fetching URL is a bad example, I did learn how you are using `Array.tryPick` in case something returns `None` but I don't have any function returning `None`, either they return a typed `Result` or a typed `Error` record and error record consists of `code` and `message` fields. and `Error` record is what halts the chain, not the `None`(as in my question). I'll re-attempt this question in a different way, fetching urls took a wrong turn.

Comment: I think I can articulate it now, basically railway oriented programming with async functions, that's what I'm looking for. Context: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: re-attempting, appreciate all the help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370853/chaining-async-rest-calls-in-a-pipeline-while-managing-errors

Comment: @Developer11 I posted my answer there - tldr, I think you do not need Railway Oriented Programming to solve your problem.